# Testing Dropwizard Managed Interface- how do you manually stop a class that extends the interface?

Tags: debugging, testing, dropwizard

I have a class ConsumerManager that extends the Managed interface in Dropwizard, and I'm trying to debug it. I want to see what happens when stop() is called (stop is a method that must be overridden when implementing the Managed interface), but I can't figure out how to manually cause the class to call stop().

How would one go about this either from the IDE (I'm using Netbeans) or the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily add a REST resource that takes the managed interface as a constructor parameter and then add a GET method that invokes `stop()` on that managed interface. You could then step through this with the debugger (assuming you're launching the application from within NetBeans) after calling this resource from curl or your browser.